# Error using an Execute SQL script to load a date variable in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I'm trying to populate a variable using an Execute SQL task in SSIS.  The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE BuildControl 
(Id INT NOT NULL Identity, BuildDate Date, 
     Country char(2), BuildStatus varchar(20), 
     BuildStatusDate DateTime)
```

The SQL Statement is

```
SELECT TOP 1 ? = Id, ? = BuildDate
FROM BuildControl
WHERE BuildStatus IS NULL
ORDER BY Id
```

and it works fine if I remove the `? = BuildDate`.  The parameter mapping tab looks like this:

[image]

The error I'm recieving is this:

```
SSIS package "WFG Statement Build.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC002F210 at Get Build Data, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "SELECT TOP 1 ? = Id, ? = BuildDate
FROM BuildContr..." failed with the following error: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
Task failed: Get Build Data
Warning: 0x80019002 at WFG Statement Build: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "WFG Statement Build.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

I believe the problem is with the date output variable since when I remove it I don't have a problem.  Both the server and the version of SSIS I'm using are SQL Server 2008 R2.  The Connection Manager is an OLE DB connection using the `Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 10.0` provider.  I've tried changing the table structure to use a DateTime with no success, and tried DBDate and DBDateTime as Data Types in the Parameter Mapping page also with no success.

I'm completely baffled.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I sympathize, working with variables in SSIS is a massive PITA.  Can you pull the date value into a text variable instead, and work with it from there?

Comment: If I have to I will.  However I would rather not go through the extra step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try mapping your result set, not parameters. The setting is similar; the Result Names are `0` and `1` and the `? =` are not necessary in your select statement.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id, BuildDate
FROM BuildControl
WHERE BuildStatus IS NULL
ORDER BY Id
```

Also, make sure your Result Set is set to `Single row`.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  I've done result sets before but not single row ones.  I'm still curious why the other method is failing though.

Comment: Looking at your settings again, I see what you were doing--I missed the `output` direction setting. I can't say why that shouldn't work, other than that *SSIS SQL task parameters are flaky as heck*. Possibly [this](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/03/12/SSIS_3A00_-Datetime-variables-don_2700_t-always-do-what-you-expect.aspx)?

Comment: I noticed a few things saying that changing the OUTPUT setting fixed this particular problem, unfortunately I need the setting that way so that I can get the value out of the query, and not pass one in.  I'm going to try the result set idea in the morning.

Comment: @SQLFox [That](http://dbareactions.tumblr.com/post/63475332087/when-i-upvote-an-answer-at-dba-stackexchange-com)'s for you, thanks!